# What serializer is Android using behind Bundle.putSerializable?

Tags: android

What serializer is Android using behind [Bundle.putSerializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29)?

The reason I want to know is that I want to write a unit test that checks if my class actually serializes successfully. It implementing `java.io.Serializable` is no guarantee for that.

**edit**: I guess I can rephrase my question to "how do I serialize an Object implementing Serializable interface in a Unit test running Junit under Java with Robolectric"

Comment: every object that implements the serializable interface

Comment: That is `java.io.Serializable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming it uses standard [Java Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). To simulate, call the [writeObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29)-method on an `ObjectOutputStream` with the serializable object as input. Then deserialize with `readObject()` and check the result.

Example code:

```
class SomeSerializableObject implements Serializable {
    public String SomeProperty;
}

@Test
public void SomeSerializableObject_IsSerializable() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Setup
    SomeSerializableObject obj = new SomeSerializableObject();
    obj.SomeProperty = "Hi!";
    ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream(10000);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);

    // Act
    os.writeObject(obj);

    // Assert
    byte[] raw = bo.toByteArray();
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(raw));
    SomeSerializableObject result = (SomeSerializableObject) is.readObject();
    assertEquals("Hi!", result.SomeProperty);
}
```